# Setting component values before render

Tags: reactjs

I have the following component :

```
export default function EventContainer({ routes, children }) {
  const location = useLocation();
  const currentRoute = routes.find((route) => route.path === location.pathname);

  return (
    <div>
      {currentRoute.name}
    </div>
  );
}
```

It works fine. But I am wondering if i should do the currentRoute logic in a useEffect instead of the way i am doing it now. I am worried if the routes array grows it might take longer and then i'll run into errors because the data is not available for render.

The main question is : Is it necessary to have a useEffect here or is the way I am doing it now actually fine ...

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have like 10k routes, you will hardly notice any performance differences in real-life scenarios. It is just an O(n) scan after all.

> i'll run into errors because the data is not available for render.

I don't quite get what you mean here, the entire function in your code is synchronized. `currentRoute` will always exist before rendering (it will be `undefined if the pathname matches nothing obviously)